# How to set background colors of active div and previous div as red in React.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have created dynamic boxes. I want to change the background color of the active `div` to blue when clicked. When I click the 1st cell it should change to blue, then when I click the 2nd cell the 1st and 2nd `div`s should be blue, and when I click the 3rd cell the 2nd and 3rd should be blue while the 1st cell should change to red.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class ThinkingReact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getRow: [],
      values: [
        { id: 0 },
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 },
        { id: 5 },
        { id: 6 },
        { id: 7 },
        { id: 8 },
        { id: 9 },
        { id: 10 },
        { id: 11 },
        { id: 12 },
        { id: 13 },
        { id: 14 },
        { id: 15 }
      ]
    };
  }
  changeColor = (i, e) => {
    this.setState({ cr_id: i });
  };
  render() {
    let _C_value = this.state.cr_id;

    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.state.values.map((v) => (
          <div
            value={v.id}
            key={v.id}
            className="column"
            style={{
              background: v.id === _C_value ? "blue" : ""
            }}
            onClick={this.changeColor.bind(this, v.id)}
          >
            {v.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ThinkingReact;
```

Comment: So the current active and the last active item should be blue and all other items should be red?

Comment: set previous and current id in the state. Update the color based on the state value.

Answer (score 0):

try below approach

```
this.state = {
  getRow: [],
  values: [
    { id: 0, name: 'sarun', visited: false },
    { id: 1, name: 'abc', visited: false },
    { id: 2, name: 'abc4', visited: false },
    { id: 3, name: 'abc1', visited: false },
    { id: 4, name: 'test78', visited: false }
  ],
 selected: {prevId: '', currentId: ''}
};
```

Update prev,current Id and visited on click on the div. (in changeColor method)

Access the state value and check the condition inside the style property,

```
const selectedVal = this.state.selected;
 style={{ background: (v.id === selectedVal.prevId || v.id === selectedVal.currentId) 
? "blue" : (v.visited ? "red": "")}}
```